# Flow union in object values not working as expected

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a following code. For some reason, Flow rejects it.

```
class A {}
class B {}

type Intersection = (A | B);

var myMap: {
    a: A;
    b: B;
} = {
    a: new A(),
    b: new B()
}

var getter = function (name: string): () => Intersection {
    return function (): Intersection {
        return myMap[name];
    }
}

var bGetter: () => B = getter("b");
```

I see no error in the code. However, Flow rejects it with the following:

> /srv/webwallet/app/scripts/angularHelper.js:14:22,22: A This type is
>   incompatible with /srv/webwallet/app/scripts/angularHelper.js:12:7,7:
>   B
>
> Found 1 error

Why doesn't the code check, and how to make it check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

`type Intersection = (A | B);`

to

`type Intersection = (A & B);`

The "|" operator is a disjoint union.

Comment: I don't understand why intersection `&` is the correct answer. "An intersection type requires a value to be all of the input types." In this case, `bGetter` ends up being of type `B` and not `A` so it doesn't meet the definition. It seems that function prototypes in particular, for some reason, require `&` to mean 'or'. What am I missing?